# Client receive json object to javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I want my server to send a JSON object to a javascript on the client's side. How can the client get the object into his javascript and not show the object on screen?

In my server :

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(jsonObj);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Probably, you're looking for XHR/AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery i will show you a quick example of how things work:

Client

```
$.get('youserver.com/', {mydata: 'content'}, function(response){
   //callback triggered when server responds
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Server

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.params.mydata === 'content'){
    res.end("you sent content");
  }  else {
    res.end("you sent something else");
  }
});
```

Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: can you explain a little more? what is req.params.mydata==='content'
and what is res.end. 
sorry i dont know much - i'm pretty new to node.js.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: you also seem to be new to javascript then :) "req" is the parameter object which passes request variables from the http layer to your express route. params is an object nested inside the req object which consists of your parameters passed with the request. mydata is the data string you have passed on the client side. you might want to "npm install body-parser" (and also read through its docs of course) basicly this is just a communication set up between your client/server. You should read how this works in detail in some tutorial for example on scotch.io

Comment: hhh .i'm relativly new. I started learning it 2 week ago this semester. Anyway thank you very much!.

Comment: Its easy to learn the basics, just have a look at how the javascript stack works. Check out some articles on http and just find out stuff by simple testing :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `res.json()` method

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json(jsonObj);
});
```

Comment: problem is getting json on frontend, but not sending it on backend