# Server sends data to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my express project I want my server to send a JSON object to the client. The client uses a script to display the data it recieves and so I dont want to the data sent from the server being seen on the screen directly, I want it to go through the javascript first.
I tried many ways to send any data and non was successfull:

client:

```
$.get('http://localhost:1337/', {mydata: 'content'}, function(response){
   console.log(response);
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:1337/',
  data: {
    mydata: "content"
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (json) {
    console.log(json);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
    console.log(error);
  },
  type: 'GET'
});
```

server:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.render('main',{data:'text'})
    });
```

or

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
         res.render('main','text2')
        });
```

Is there a way to send data to the client that will go first to the javascript in the sended page?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server, use `res.json({data:'text'});` instead of `res.render(...)` to send json. That should do the trick.

Update:

If you want to build a single page application with multiple ajax requests you should use different routes for those. One will send the page and the other the data.

However, if your application is small and simple, you could continue doing what you did, but get the data via javascript variable instead of an ajax request. For that in your template you'll have to do something like that (assuming it's jade):

```
script(type='text/javascript')                                                   
  var local_data =!{JSON.stringify(data)};
```

The page will be rendered with the following HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var local_data = {"data":"text"};
</script>
```

You than in your script can do the following:

```
//Your javascript 

function displayPage(data){
     //display logic here
     console.log(data);   
}

displayPage(local_data);
```

Comment: But then how do i send the page i want to display? the client script that should recieve the data is being used there

Comment: can you explain a little what this will do?

Comment: Yes, you will have a global javascript variable local_data on your page. Witch will contain all the data you passed to the render function. You than can use it to display your page.

Comment: How can i acces it via the client's javascript?

Comment: my web page shows : local_data ="data2"; and does not render the page when i ran the function. and if I dont run the function it still writes local_data ="data2"; on the screen but the page is rendered

Comment: I ran debug on the browser and saw the error : local_data is not defined

Comment: Thank you!I changed the position of the var in the jade page and it works now!